# Is there a Stack Exchange site for Law Questions? If not, why not?

Tags: discussion, legal

I think a Legal Stack Overflow would be an excellent resource. Why doesn't such a thing exist? If it doesn't, I'd like to create one.

Comment: This belongs on [a51]? There already are proposals for that, but none in beta.

Comment: Related: [Why “Software Law” was closed](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/5155/why-software-law-was-closed) and [Why “Intellectual Property Law” was closed](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/5158/why-intellectual-property-law-was-closed) on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com).

Comment: ^ links broken.

Comment: There is proposal http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law

Comment: I think this is a really bad idea. Any stupid troll has freedom to answer any law question and this can result into serious problems...

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law is currently in the Commitment phase.

Comment: @Aryan, just like any other stackoverflow...

Comment: @ArulxZ: "Any stupid troll has freedom to answer any law question and this can result into serious problems." -->  This is true for ANY StackExchange (SX) site, which is why SX has a system of voting, reputation and commentary to help the interested reader evaluate the quality and reliability of answers. It's not a perfect system, but anyone who thinks it is probably doesn't belong on the internet in the first place. :-)

Comment: If SX did create a Law site, there would probably have to be a disclaimer somewhere to this effect: "ignorantia legis neminem excusat" (ignorance of the law excuses nobody). A Law SX site could HELP direct people to the right resources (e.g. legal documents) for better info, and people could even advise others, but all of this is with the understanding that it may not be solid advice.

Comment: Not sure when it launched, but it looks like there is now a site for this at http://law.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 105):

I asked a question and was given legal advice by BigSchween03 on your website.  Apparently his
claim that it was perfectly legal to "take what's yours" wasn't based on current jurisprudence.

I was subsequently arrested and jailed for over a year.  During the term of my incarceration, I was beaten and suffered degrading treatment by my co-inmates.

Because of this bad legal advice your website gave me, I am now suing you for everything you have ever owned, including that Star Wars lego set with the Hoth rebel base you loved when you were 7.  I will be joined in my lawsuit by everybody else who got bad legal advice from users on your website.

Now, if you will excuse me, I have some more legal questions about my upcoming case I must submit to the community.

Comment: That's what disclaimers are for. ;)

Comment: @Bobby: On your advice, I placed a disclaimer on my door that any female who enters may be molested.  I was subsequently arrested and spent the next five years in jail.  I am now going to sue you for everything you have owned, wanted to own, have seen, your family members have owned or thought about owning, and stuff you couldn't possibly want or afford.

Comment: @Will don't give a ♦: If I'm allowed to quote Wikipedia: "[The courts may or may not give effect to the disclaimer depending on whether the law permits exclusion of liability in the particular situation...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disclaimer)" But I understand your point *absolutely*, a disclaimer is of course not an allround-always-working excuse, but I think (and by that I mean that I have no idea about U.S. jurisdiction whatsoever) that it is in this case. *tbc*

Comment: If the user hits agree when he gets told that "we can't guarantee anything and Stack Exchange had nothing to do with it" then that's his problem. I mean, Microsoft never got suit for all the havoc their software caused. Neither got General Motors. I've also never heard that a forum user got suit based on their advice to anyone.

Comment: @Bobby: If you have a website *who's sole purpose is to answer legal questions* can you possibly suggest that a disclaimer saying "don't take our advice, consult your lawyer, lol" will work in a court of law?

Comment: @Will A disclaimer stating you intend to break the law is not what is under discussion here.

Comment: @Renesis: Disclaimers may save you from legal liabilities in some cases but it won't save your ass from having to prove it in court.  And, again, you are *creating* a website *specifically* to share legal advice.  How can you claim that you are protected by a disclaimer stating that the legal advice given on the website should not be taken seriously?

Comment: @Will - Don't misconstrue my point.  All I'm saying is that a straw man argument doesn't really add anything to this discussion.

Comment: @Renesis: If you believe the disclaimer is a straw argument, you should have atted-Bobby, not me.

Comment: @Will Your argument in the second comment: The absurdity of a disclaimer announcing you intend to break the law.  Bobby didn't suggest a disclaimer that would allow you to break the law.  That's a straw man argument, then.

Comment: Is this an argument against law questions or an argument against all advice?

Comment: @hippietrail: Nobody has gone to jail for suggesting the wrong GoF pattern, but plenty are in jail now for providing and taking incompetent legal advice.

Comment: Am I the only one who feels that there is something terribly wrong with a legal system that makes it impossible for people to safely discuss the law "to the best of their knowledge".  How are people supposed to learn about the law and how are they expected to know it in order to keep it, if we can't openly discuss it?

Comment: "disclaimers! disclaimers as far as the eyes can see!!" even then,  I don't think that keeps people from *trying* to sue you, and wasting yours and everyone else's time.

Comment: Isn't every contributor on every StackExchange site (and SE itself, for that matter) open to this same kind of risk? If I give someone advice on StackOverflow and their acting upon it somehow costs them their job, couldn't they sue me and SO over that? Why does it seem like only doctors and lawyers are paranoid about this sort of thing? Is it just that the crazy amount of litigation in their industries make a suit much more likely? Or is there some other fundamental difference?

Comment: @ToddR: giving legal advice is 100% different than everything else, as you are ... pooping in the bear's woods, so to speak.  And medicine is a close second, for obvious reasons (I took your advice and blarg).  Yeah, you can get in legal trouble everywhere, but the risk is not equal in all fields.

Comment: @Won't: You did?!  That was a stupid mistake now, wasn't it.  Hopefully now you've learned your lesson, and won't be so gullible as to take things you read online on non-government websites as infallible fact.  Also, be thankful you were only in prison for a relatively short time, and that you're out now and can move on.

Comment: @Won't: And we're all here for you if you need further emotional support.  Also, don't sue Stack Exchange, Inc.  You won't win, and you'll just be wasting yet more of your own and others' precious and wonderful lives.

Comment: I need some legal advice about software for myself. I'm not so much asking 'will I get in trouble for doing this' as much as I'm asking 'what can you tell me about this, and what else should I think about/consider.'

Comment: Yes, but that is for everything. Bad advise in any discipline can cause you be to killed, maimed, or suffer horribly.
If we took this argument as correct, advice on how to operate a chainsaw would be the riskiest advise to give, not legal advise.

Comment: I don't think it's so much "pooping in the Bear's woods" as it is the "reasonable expectations" that come into play when you represent yourself as an expert on the law because such representations are regulated by licensing boards.  This is also true of medicine: you get in trouble if you give medical advice not because you piss off doctors, but because you represent yourself as an expert under a regime that has a legal framework for such representation.

Comment: Of all places with a legal system in the world, don't run the site in the United States of America. Problem solved (at least until the U.S. corporate juggernaut machine forces something like the [<del>PITA</del>TTIP](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transatlantic_Trade_and_Investment_Partnership) on the civilized world).

Comment: I once got some very bad legal advice in written form.   I'm suing the company that manufactured the paper it was written on.  Gotta love this system.  Wish me luck.  : )

Comment: So here's my digest so far: An SO for law should not be prohibited because SO/others could be liable for bad law advice. Counter: Post up a disclaimer/make everyone agree to something that limits such liablity. Counter to counter: A disclaimer may not adequately discharge such liability. So this is what I'm wondering (I am no lawyer!): in such a case as this, where someone reasonably fears a palpable liability, can't one ask a court for declarative relief? I.e., go to the court, say here's what we want to do, here's our disclaimer, here's what we're assuming it protects us from--IS THIS VALID?

Comment: Sorry, typo in first line. "Should not be" should be "should be." Time to edit has expired. Also, that was a fun line to type.

Comment: @bgfriend0 I have no idea if the concept of declarative relief exists and if it is accepted in America.  I'd doubt it highly.  Consider--my horribly corrupt friend is a judge.  He gives me DR that I can walk into banks and rob them.  Does it hold?

Comment: @Won't I think that's reductio ad absurdum. I think we have to assume the justice system is not broken and corrupt, otherwise we could come up with counterexamples for everything. Anyway, I was curious so Google'd declarative relief and found this on Wikipedia: "A declaratory judgment... is the legal determination of a court that resolves legal uncertainty for the litigants. It is a form of legally binding preventive adjudication by which a party involved in an actual or possible legal matter can ask a court to conclusively rule on and affirm the rights, duties, or obligations...."

Comment: @bgfriend0 If you can find citations where it has been used to provide a service sweeping immunity from any and all lawsuits brought by users of that service, then add an answer to the question and make an argument that it's totally risk-free.  I'm not really interested in it otherwise, as it does not provide adequate protection in this situation.

Comment: Lol, @Won't, I think that's another *extreme* argument. By no means is this asking for sweeping immunity. It's established law that some disclaimers can discharge liability--in our case, disclaimers that warn not to use the forum for legal advice. You'd be asking for a declaratory ruling validating the disclaimer--no more, no less. It's not even immunity. Either the disclaimer is valid, or it's not, and the disclaimer is scoped to discharging liability accrued for misusing the forum as legal advice. Again, I'm no attorney, so if you are I'd give your opinion more weight. I'm just curious.

Comment: @bgfriend0 I'm not an attorney, but I play one on the internets.

Answer (score 51):

The law stackexchange is available:

https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A downvote, eh?  I chuckle in your general direction.  ;-D

Comment: It wasn't me. I propose we make every member of Meta who didn't downvote this post a comment, so we can deduce who it was and give them the third degree!

Comment: Good projects! pity that all of them have been deleted :(

Comment: All of these proposals have been removed.

Comment: @AdamDavis,  Why are **All** three proposals deleted?

Comment: @pacerier if a proposal doesn't gain enough attention quickly enough, it is closed and has to be resubmitted. Go to http://area51.stackexchange.com and read the faq and help questions for more info.

Comment: Dammit... I reaaaaaaly wanted to post a question on one of those, then tried to support, then sadly all were closed. mainly Software-Law

Comment: area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law is currently in the Commitment phase.

Comment: A bit late but... the downvote wasn't me!

Comment: @AdamDavis It's now out of beta.

Answer (score 22):

I'm sorry to see that 3 Area51 proposals related to law were closed in 2012, and wonder if there is still interest in a revised approach.

Re the liability concerns, there is substantial protection in at least one big state.  This is from the Wikipedia article on perhaps the largest existing online law site, Nolo.com:

> In 1997, the Texas Unauthorized Practice of Law Committee (a committee of the Texas Supreme Court) opened investigations on Nolo and similar publishers, inquiring as to whether their publications constituted the practicing law without a licence. Saying that the investigation was "the first step toward widespread state censorship",[6] Nolo sued, seeking a declaratory judgment that its publications were legal. It was joined in the action by the American Association of Law Libraries and the Texas Library Association. In response, the Texas Legislature enacted HR 1507, which expressly exempted websites and textbooks from accusations of practicing law without a license, providing they "clearly and conspicuously state that the products are not a substitute for the advice of an attorney".[7] In light of this, the court committee dropped its contest of Nolo's suit.[8]
>    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nolo.com

Comment: There is still interest.

Comment: The Internet needs a law advise forum.

Comment: Cyberspace vs Engler might be of some help

Comment: If people are so concerned about legal action being taken for poor legal advice, then a non-US site is the answer where people are free to contribute.

Answer (score 12):

I think this would be great, but I don't think it can work.

I am not a lawyer (blah blah), but I have a few lawyers in my family, and I have always found law to be an interesting topic (though I have never had any interest in actually practicing).  I think that one of the reasons real lawyers would not want to give advice like this is that it is hard for them to know the whole situation in this type of forum, so they would not be able to give sound advice, and also, a lawyer giving legal advice may establish an attorney-client relationship in some jurisdictions, regardless of whether any fees were paid.  This can mean the lawyer can be bound to certain obligations, such as attorney-client privilege.  Likewise, discussing legal matters in a public forum may not make a whole lot of sense.

That being said, it would be awesome if there was a site like SO where I could research law-related questions that pop into my head, and get well-informed responses.

Comment: I have a question. Is a hotel booking a "good" (which you paid for in advance) or a "service"? I believe such a question could be answered by a lawyer without too much additional context.

Comment: @PP in which country? There are more than 150 countries in the world, probably with differing views on the question.

Comment: @Pekka: Obviously that question only makes sense in the context of a jurisdiction, much the way a programming question usually only makes sense in the context of one of the 150+ programming languages in the world.

Comment: @Gabe: Right, but those 150+ programming languages are used all over the world, whereas Italian law will rarely be applied outside Italy. That makes a major difference for me.

Comment: @Hendick: How does that matter? There are far more Italians than there are AS/400 programmers, yet there's no problem asking an AS/400 question on SO.

Comment: @Gabe: But will there really be so many more interested in _Italian law_ than in AS/400? Still you have a point. Let me add another point: It would be a bit awkward to have a site about Italian law on an English-speaking network, wouldn't it? (Incidentally, note the "r" in my name.)

Comment: @Hendrick: Italy, being part of the EU, probably has much law in common with English-speaking countries like UK and Ireland. Plus, English-speaking Italian legal experts could answer useful questions like "My website does X. What should I know to serve customers in Italy?". (I saw the "r" but made a typo.)

Comment: I'm having a hard time accepting the statement "Italy, being part of the EU, probably has much law in common with English-speaking countries", even just thinking about English-speaking countries

Answer (score 6):

As of 2012, [the sites that Adam Davis mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25363/is-there-a-stack-exchange-site-for-law-questions-if-not-why-not/91153#91153) are closed.

There are currently two new proposals:

- [Legal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48901/legal)

  - For businesses and individuals with questions about the law (who to talk to and what paperwork to fill out).
- [Legal Doctrine, Policy, Practice, and other law-related topics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52687/legal-doctrine-policy-practice-and-other-law-related-topics)

  - For legal academics, students, practitioners, and others with an interest in or question about the law.

Comment: These are now closed as well.