# Where can I ask questions about the law, immigration, and other matters related to bureaucracy?

Tags: support, scope, site-recommendation

Where can I ask questions about the law, immigration, and other matters related to bureaucracy?

Comment: related: [Which is the appropriate SO site for legal matters?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129333/165773)

Comment: There is also http://travel.stackexchange.com for certain types of immigration related questions but it sounds like it might not be quite the right choice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a Stack Exchange site for Law Questions? If not, why not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25363/is-there-a-stack-exchange-site-for-law-questions-if-not-why-not)

Answer (score 7):

[Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) is now <strike>in private beta</strike> fully graduated. We have [<strike>one question</strike> 326 questions](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immigration) so far on immigration, and it's perfectly on topic there -- as are questions about law in general, within the scope detailed [in the help center](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 7):

[Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) is probably a good place for the immigration questions, and if your law and bureaucracy questions pertain to moving to a new country, they would mostly belong there too. They have tags like [immigration](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immigration), [driving-license](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/driving-license), [banking](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/banking), [health-insurance](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-insurance) and so on