# Why doesn't SE redirect or suggest other sites for out of scope questions?

Tags: discussion

This question is a followup to my earlier question ([Questions related to US Immigration and tax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190058/questions-related-to-us-immigration-and-tax)).

I understand SE hosts only question and answer sites. And SE doesn't cover many topics (ex: Immigration, Law etc..) and other learning activities like only discussions, sharing experiences, exchanging opinions etc.

Questions falling under such categories are simply getting closed on SE. I have seen other sites like Yahoo! Answers redirecting to SE when they feel it is best suited to SE.

Why doesn't SE redirect, and allow the community to redirect, to other sites for the questions and activities which are not in SE's scope?

Comment: It's not in SE's scope to link to other resources.  That's how I see it, though.

Comment: Why would anyone here know where to ask such questions?

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, there are simply far too many other sites to be listed and for Stack Exchange to keep tabs on. These sites come and go and the list would be in a constant state of flux.

Secondly, it's not Stack Exchange's place to promote one site over another. If a site wants get the benefit of showing itself to the Stack Exchange audience there are paid advertisements for that.

If you think that a question that doesn't fit on Stack Exchange then feel free to link to somewhere else in the comments. However, make it clear if you are affiliated with the site otherwise the comment may well get deleted as spam.

Answer (score 0):

In the past there were redirects to more sites. However those sites have highly specific scope. For example, on many sites it's cool to ask how to use an X, and to mention you have the Y brand or model, but it's not cool to ask what X you should buy or if Y is a good X.

Generally speaking people on SO don't know those nuances. They just know "this doesn't belong here." So they sent bad migrations over. When questions were closed and deleted on the target site everyone felt bad. So that doesn't happen any more.

I [once suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79646/147247) that you be able to send to sites where you had a decently large rep, but that never happened.

Comment: The question isn't about migrations to other SE sites, but directing users to non-SE sites.