# "Modified" link sometimes takes me to footer

Tags: bug, design, questions, last-activity, mobile-firefox

On the site's start page, if I open the "modified" link of one of the listed questions in a new background tab, I sometimes end up in the footer rather than at the modifed question or answer.

For example, [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87346/where-can-i-ask-questions-about-the-law-immigration-and-other-matters-related/392212#392212) allows me to reproduce this behavior at will. If I simply click the link, I'm taken to a deleted spam post (this obviously requires the 10k+ privilege to view deleted posts) but if I open in a background tab, I end up looking at the site's footer when I visit that tab.

I originally thought this was specific to deleted posts, but I have subsequently also experienced it with non-deleted posts such as [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390137/is-se-in-violation-of-the-cc-by-sa-4-0-license-by-not-providing-data-dumps?lastactivity).

When I originally posted this question, out of the maybe five "modified" links I had clicked recently, two exhibited this behavior.

This is on an iPhone 12 Mini running Firefox 116.0 (33174); to open a background tab, long press on a link and select "open in new tab" from the menu (similar to ctrl-click on desktop).

Comment: Repro'd on Android 10, Firefox 116.3.0, no repro in chrome.

Comment: No repro, however the anchors on SE were never reliable for me, and rarely take me to the correct post. However never to the footer, usually to some random post, or just the question itself many times. Probably browser issue so I never reported it.

Comment: See also now https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426997/clicking-on-inbox-notifications-in-mobile-firefox-on-ios-takes-me-to-footer-of-l