# Any plans for legal stackoverflow?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Stack Overflow for Law Questions? If not, why not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25363/is-there-a-stack-overflow-for-law-questions-if-not-why-not)

I hope this is on-topic for this site, and if not my apologies. It would be wonderful if there were attorneys willing to offer answers to legal questions. Are there any plans for adding this q/a site?

Answer (score 5):

If you're curious what new sites are being considered, take a look at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com).

There currently is a [Legal SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/24586/laws-legal-questions) site proposed already, so you could always throw your support behind it.

Comment: Thank you! I have committed and put the word out on Facebook.

Comment: that is are removed now, but this one is still alive, if you follow it/ask questions it would help move it to the next stage:
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52687/legal-doctrine-policy-practice-and-other-law-related-topics

Answer (score 3):

StackExchanges are added to the network after being proposed by users. Head over to [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) to see if there is a proposal that you would be interested in. You can follow it, and if enough people support it then it might eventually turn into an SE of its own.

Comment: Great! I have committed and put the word out on Facebook.