# Which is the appropriate SO site for legal matters?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Stack Overflow for Law Questions? If not, why not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25363/is-there-a-stack-overflow-for-law-questions-if-not-why-not)
>   [Any plans for legal stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122494/any-plans-for-legal-stackoverflow)

I need to get some help with a legal matter regarding the web and technology.

I couldn't find any obvious site in the list, maybe there is one in Area 51?
If SO is not the place for these kind of questions I'm sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Overflow generally won't be the right place for legal questions.

There are at least three proposals on Area 51 that might, or might not, fit, depending on exactly what you're after:

- [Laws & Legal Questions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/24586/laws-legal-questions)
- [Software Law](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3527/software-law)
- [Intellectual Property Law](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3346/intellectual-property-law)

Comment: Intellectual property law fits perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: also:
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52687/legal-doctrine-policy-practice-and-other-law-related-topics
if you follow it/ask questions it would help move it to the next stage.