# Why is there no Stack Exchange community about law?

Tags: discussion

Why is there no Stack Exchange community about law?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law

Comment: As well as [law.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148725), [Any plans for legal stackoverflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122494) and  [Which is the appropriate SO site for legal matters?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129333)

Comment: Law highly differs between states and countries, so we would need separate sites for each state/country.. I don't think it's a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

<s>There's a proposal for one: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law.</s>

If it attracts enough people, we'll set up a site on the topic.

There is a [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/) site now.
See also: [How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site)