# law.stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, site-proposal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Stack Exchange site for Law Questions? If not, why not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25363/is-there-a-stack-exchange-site-for-law-questions-if-not-why-not)

Site that will allow to ask questions about the law system, every each country System work in different way so users can ask about different languages (countries).

from programming point of view people can ask questions about different licenses, Term of Services EULA, Public domain and other things not related to computers and internet.

Comment: Head over to [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) instead and see if it already has been proposed or not.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry I thought that this is the place for this kind of things.

Comment: I think I need to write a reeducation post regarding down-votes here. What the hell, people, really?! It's not like meta is the easiest thing to search. Great job on being the typical ass-hats that we've become so infamous for being.

Comment: @Tim it's possible we've become less ass-hatty in the intervening years. Yeah now that I say it out loud it doesn't seem super plausible

Comment: There is currently one proposal in area51. In order to move it to the next level, you can upvote sample questions in: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Site requests are the domain of [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), where you can propose new subjects and organize a community around these.

There were some more law related site proposals made in the past (proposals no longer visible):

- [Law & Government](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41369/law-government) -- *For people who have questions regarding law, government, etc.*
- [Rules and Laws for IT](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40687/rules-and-laws-for-it) -- *For bloggers, Internet users, software developers, social network users, and webmasters.*
- [Legal Interpretations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43309/legal-interpretations) -- *For this site is for Americans to ask questions pertaining to legal interpretations of domestic laws, and for European laymen to answer those questions.*

All three failed to make it through the Area51 process though; Q&A about law is *hard* and fraught with legal pitfalls, and I can imagine that legal experts are cautious about participating in such a site.

In April 2014, yet another [Law Q&A site has been proposed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law):

> Proposed Q&A site for experts in the law, and those who want to find our more about specific local, national or international laws, or those who want to find out about concepts regarding laws in general. The site is not for specific legal advice.

which clearly tries to steer away from specific legal advice.

Comment: And there is also Rights, they can be merge into one site, I propose it as a question, becasue I don't see a way to propose new one.

Comment: those are removed now, but this one is still alive, if you follow it/ask questions it would help move it to the next stage:
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52687/legal-doctrine-policy-practice-and-other-law-related-topics

Comment: @jimasp, that is closed too?

Comment: Three broken links.

Comment: @kenorb: *There were some more law related site proposals made **in the past*** and *All three **failed to make it** through the Area51 process*.

Comment: @kenorb: and the links are not broken; they are clearly stating the proposal has been deleted.

Comment: All those proposals was removed but there is LAW http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law

Comment: @jcubic: thanks for the update, added.