# Which Stack Exchange site is most appropriate for asking software licensing related questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Which Stack Exchange site is most appropriate for asking software licensing related questions?

Comment: Depends.  "What kind of licenses does company X use for product Y?" No, ask X. "What license should I use?" Not unless you list specific requirements.  Otherwise it's just a list of licenses.  "What is a software license?" No, you should do some research first.

Comment: The question I asked in StackOverflow got closed which prompted me to search for the proper place to ask

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799296/future-of-a-servicestack-based-solution-in-the-context-of-licensing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

From the [help center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> ### What topics can I ask about here?
>
> - algorithm and data structure concepts
> - design patterns
> - developer testing
> - development methodologies
> - freelancing and business concerns
> - quality assurance
> - software architecture
> - software engineering
> - **software licensing**

Comment: With the caveat that none of us are lawyers, so you're essentially asking for free legal advice from unqualified strangers on the Internet.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You're sure that there isn't a single lawyer on P.SE?  Although if there were, they wouldn't be on retainer, and thus wouldn't be legally responsible for any advice they may provide.

Comment: @Servy: I believe that at least in some jurisdictions they could be legally responsible for the advice they give, and because of this anyone who really is a lawyer who gives you free advice without knowing all the details is a bad lawyer because they don't even understand this. But IANAL.

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't a StackExchange for lawyers and legal issues yet but then again [I can understand why](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25363/is-there-a-stack-exchange-site-for-law-questions-if-not-why-not)

Comment: This answer is now out of date.  Software licensing questions (i.e. legal advice) are no longer accepted on [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (which I guess used to be called programmers?)

Answer (score 0):

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58715/open-source-licensing?referrer=ZWR0gdm0sttFtbu7jPSDPA2

If the proposal gets accepted, that is. Now is your chance to make it happen ;-)