# Where to ask my question about writing a disclaimer for a program?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I asked [a question on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39054/opensource-to-reduce-incidence-of-work-related-musculoskeletal-disorders-of-the) about a disclaimer for my app.

It was put as on hold as off topic because the site is only for code review. Could anybody suggest on which Stack Exchange site I could ask this question?

I'm pasting it here for reference:

> I am about to publish an open source program aimed to reduce incidence
>   of work-related musculoskeletal disorders of the hand and wrist. The
>   principle is quite simple: The program can track work time to make
>   sure it is being run all day long on a computer and on top of this
>   physiotherapy exercises are regularly proposed to the user to relax
>   muscles of the hand, wrist, arm and shoulder thus reducing the
>   incidence of the fast growing new pathology.
>
> Now my question is I want to make sure I cannot be sued because of any
>   usage of the exercises leading to any health problems. Could anybody
>   help on the terms of this text to clearly states the program comes
>   without any warranty and the user itself is responsible for any health
>   damage caused when following the exercises ?
>
> This is the text appearing in a message box the first time the program
>   starts, the user can click away the dialog so that it never appears
>   again:
>
> Please read this carefully, this program can damage your health !
>
> On top of tracking your time at work, this program proposes some
>   exercises to relax muscles or increase musculatures of hands and arms
>   when working with a computer. This program and the exercises come
>   WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY and the user is THE ONLY RESPONSIBLE for any
>   health problems that could arise.
>
> HINT: This exercises MUST BE ABSOLUTELY AVOIDED if you feel even the
>   SLIGHTEST pain ANYWHERE in your body. In such case refer to your
>   physical to make sure all of these exercises are not unhealthy for
>   you.
>
> Exercises come without any warranty of improving your health, they are
>   ONLY hints YOU decide to follow on YOUR OWN responsibility.
>
> Click on Yes if understand and agree with this terms and you would
>   like to see regularly exercises, click on No if you do not want to
>   activate this feature.

Comment: What made you think that was on-topic at Code Review?  Read the Help Center/On Topic article at each site to find out what is on-topic there.

Comment: I agree but I did not know where to ask .. as I needed a review of a text I thought it may have partially fit.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Now my question is I want to make sure I cannot be sued because of any usage of the exercises leading to any health problems. Could anybody help on the terms of this text to clearly states the program comes without any warranty and the user itself is responsible for any health damage caused when following the exercises ?

It's a legal question that is likely to be off-topic on all SE sites at the moment.

I hate when people throw "ask a lawyer" comments at questions that can be answered satisfactorily with some Googling, but in this case, you really, really want to talk to a lawyer. Even if it *were* on topic on some SE site.

You don't want to put your legal future in the hands of some random people on the Internet, do you?

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no SE site for questions related to law, [and there probably won't ever be one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25363/is-there-a-stack-exchange-site-for-law-questions-if-not-why-not).

You need to consult a lawyer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that this question would be on-topic for *any* Stack Exchange site. No site that I know of covers legal documents such as your EULA that your question was about. Maybe you would ask a lawyer or another person who specializes in EULA's and legal documents.